# Looking for a suggestion on how to go about looping through rows of a table and changing a value based on other values with the same ID

Tags: sql-server, foreach, iteration

I am looking for some ideas on the best way to go about doing this.

I would like to use something like a for each loop, but I know that can be difficult and not good practice in SQL. I have a table full of 'comments' of which each have a unique `commentID`. It is associated with a table of 'Deals' by the `DealID`. Each comment has a `DealID` associated with it, and since multiple comments can be made on a single deal, several comments may have the same `DealID` associated with them.

I have a `CurrentComment` attribute in my comments table which is either `0` or `1` (1 being the most recent comment) because of some issues in our DB, I had to reset every Comment to have a 0 for the 'current comment' value.

What I want to do is go through the entire table of comments, and for each unique `DealID`, set the most recently made comment (associated with that `DealID`) to have a value of `1` for the current comment.

I'm thinking I would want to look at all of the comments associated with a single `DealID`, and the largest `CommentID` value would be the most recently made comment, so I would change that `CurrentComment` Value.

Any input/suggestions on how to go about something like this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a for loop to do this. Sql Server is set up to do the exact thing you are asking about, you just have to think about the problem a little differently. Sql Server brings back all of the rows you will need to update, assuming your criteria is set correctly. You just need to specify how you want to update your columns. You can use values from other tables or you can you specific numbers.

I would recommend sorting your data using a date value, if you have one. Updating a comment that was made today (rather than one from yesterday) is a better method because you are certain that you are updating the most recent comment.

```
Update d
Set CurrentComment = 1
From    Deals d
Where   not exists ( Select top 1 1
        From Deals dd
        Where d.CommentId < dd.CommentID
        and     dd.DealId = d.DealId)
```